# Write streaming collection to file Java-Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a server running Monogdb, which also has a collection named `mycoll`. New documents are inserted to the collection continuously. My intention is to have a local file with a copy of all the documents of the collection. My current approach is the following:

```
String host = "myHost";
int port = 3717;
String user = "user";
String password = "pass";
String databaseName = "dbName";
String collectionName = "mycoll";

MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(user, databaseName, password.toCharArray());
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(host, port), Arrays.asList(credential));
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName);
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
FindIterable<Document> cursor = collection.find();

String path = "./outputData.txt";


while(cursor.iterator().hasNext()){

        try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path, true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
        {
                out.println(cursor.iterator().next());
        } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error writing to file.");
        }

}
```

I know that I could create a buffer in order to store the data and write it afterwards, but the big problem is still not solved: that the documents are accessed one by one. Therefore, my question is: How could I access several documents at once in order to write them in `./outputData.txt`?

Comment: Create the file "outside" of the loop. Just write to it on each iteration, then close the file.

Comment: I would prefer to open the file connection one time and then he can reuse the connection again!, Also i prefer to create a new Thread to write on the file and make them write Async so that it will not affect reading the source file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, just return the `MongoCursor` by calling the `iterator()` "once", because that's all you need to do.

Then very simply create your file handle "outside" of the loop. The only thing that really belongs "inside" the loop is the actual cursor iteration and writing.

```
try {    

  MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();
  String path = "./outputData.txt";

  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
    new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path, true))
  );

  while(cursor.hasNext()){
    out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
  }

  out.flush();            // flush to ensure writes
  out.close();            // close the handle when done

} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("Error writing to file.");
}
```

Once you are finished with the cursor, simply close the file descriptor returned.

All you really need to be aware of is that you don't "create" the file descriptor or keep re-opening "within" the loop. This is the sort of thing you do once, and then simply "write out" by whatever means for each iteration.

---

As a complete listing you can then run the code just as listed against a local MongoDB on the default port with no authentication. Add options to alter that as needed, but this is the "base" code needed

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PrintWriter out  = null;
        MongoClient mongoClient = null;

        try {

            mongoClient = new MongoClient();
            MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
            MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("sample");

            out = new PrintWriter(
                    new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"))
            );

            // Clear collection and insert data
            collection.deleteMany(new Document());
            collection.insertMany(Arrays.asList(
                    new Document("a", 1),
                    new Document("a", 2),
                    new Document("a", 3)
            ));

            MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();

            while ( cursor.hasNext() ) {
                out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
                //System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
            }

            out.flush();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
            if (mongoClient != null) {
                mongoClient.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Creates a new file on each run and outputs the documents which are inserted into the collection.

Gives you a file with something like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5b0bd9576a6bfa1f30e6c320" }, "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5b0bd9576a6bfa1f30e6c321" }, "a" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5b0bd9576a6bfa1f30e6c322" }, "a" : 3 }
```

Comment: It does not return any errors, neither does it write anything to outputData.txt :/

Comment: @qwerty You need to verify you actually have something in the collection. I'll even simplify your code and call `flush()` explicitly for you. If you had not written any code like this before then you should have been explicit about that in your question.

Comment: @qwerty Added a complete listing so you cannot get it wrong. All you need do is simply run the supplied code against a default server installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **[Spring Integration + MongoDB solution](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mongodb.html#mongodb-inbound-channel-adapter)**

> ### 23.4 MongoDB Inbound Channel Adapter
>
> The MongoDb Inbound Channel Adapter is a polling consumer that reads
>   data from MongoDb and sends it as a Message payload.
>
> ```
> <int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter id="mongoInboundAdapter"
>        channel="replyChannel"
>        query="{'name' : 'Bob'}"
>        entity-class="java.lang.Object"
>        auto-startup="false">
>       <int:poller fixed-rate="100"/>
> </int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter>
> ```

### Explanation

The `MongoDB Inbound Channel Adapter` can query continiously your MongoDB database and then process the information to do whatever you want to do with it.

You can find serveral examples in the documentation.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize by using Bulk Reads with .batchsize().
When retrieving data using a cursor, you can specify the number of rows fetched in each operation using the **batchSize** clause.

example:

```
FindIterable<Document> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName)
.find()
.batchSize(arraySize);
//if you want to read 10 documents at once, 
 //set arraySize to 10.. so on

for(Document doc : collection) {
      //  save to file
     }
```

Note that the batchSize operator doesn’t actually return an array to the program — it just controls the number of documents retrieved in each network round trip. This all happens “under the hood” from your programs point of view.Hope this help

You can read more about batchsize at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/

Answer (score 0):

What i think, you need a lot like triggers. MongoDB does not have any support for triggers, however, some people have "rolled their own" using some tricks. The key here is the oplog.

When you run MongoDB in a Replica Set, all of the MongoDB actions are logged to an operations log (known as the oplog). The oplog is basically just a running list of the modifications made to the data. Replicas Sets function by listening to changes on this oplog and then applying the changes locally.

You can also read about tailable cursors. 
also, you can take help from the ongoing project for the same problem:
https://github.com/deftlabs/mongo-java-tailable-cursor